# Expected usage of Page Editor's Experience date

Tags: sitecore

I'm trying to understand the expected author experience in Page Editor when working with multiple versions of pages. If an author sets the date on the Experience tab to set a page in the future, it sticks and stays that way when opening other pages in Page Editor. We have authors who are opening the page in Page Editor and not seeing the content they expect because of the date setting. Is it expected that they have to manually manage this date when going from page to page? This seems very cumbersome.

**More specific info:** The specific issue we're having has to do with the fact that there appears to be no way to reset the button back to its default ( automatically showing the current date/time on each page load). If you manually set it back to "now" it sticks at that point in time. We have situations where authors attempt to get back to "now" by setting the date/time to the current date/time. This works for that moment, but then when they make a change to a page (causing a new version to be created with the current date/time as it's publishing restriction) and save, they're changes appear to disappear on save because the "now" they manually set in Page Editor is no longer now.

We're in the middle or rolling out workflow and this scenario is causing mass confusion with our authors.

Is there a way to reset it to automatic? Could I somehow create a custom button to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is this feature works this way to allow you to preview the site and navigate it around it as if it was another date in the future. If you had to reset it every time you went to a new page, that flow would be very cumbersome.

You are just finding the other side of the cumbersome because it is being used for an alternative flow.

Comment: That makes sense. My question was more general, so I just updated the question with the specific issue we're seeing. Please let me know your thoughts on that. Thanks!